# Is the moment generating function for a sequence $\{a_n\}$ unique?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mathematical-analysis

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence with moment generating function $A(z)=\sum_{k \ge 0} a_kz^k$.

Can a sequence $\{b_n\}$ with $b_n \neq a_n$ for at least one $n\in \mathbb N$ have the same moment generating function as $\{a_n\}$, that is $B(z)=A(z) \ \forall z$.

This is equivalent to: Is the moment generating function for a sequence $\{a_n\}$ unique ?

Comment: Afaik, it's called *ordinary* generation function in this context. MGF are a slightly different thing, conceptually. Anyway, is there a particular reason you did not post this on [math.SE]? Oh wait, you [did](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722130/is-the-moment-generating-function-for-a-sequence-a-n-unique)! Please don't do that. I'm closing it here because it's a better fit for [math.SE].